# Rails datatabels not working until search i used

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

Hi I try to use [DataTable gem](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) I have installed datatables and jquery ui:

```
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 3.3.0'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
```

And add them to my applicacion manifests:
application.js.coffee:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require turbolinks
#= require bootstrap-sprockets
#= require jquery-ui
#= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
#= require_tree .
```

application.scss:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

My payments.coffee

```
# Place all the behaviors and hooks related to the matching controller here.
# All this logic will automatically be available in application.js.
# You can use CoffeeScript in this file: http://coffeescript.org/

jQuery ->
  $('#student_payments').dataTable()
```

And actual table:

```
%table.table.table-condensed#student_payments
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= t('student.columns.first_name')
      %th= t('student.columns.last_name')
      %th= "January"
      %th= "February"
      %th= "March"
      %th= "April"
      %th= "May"
      %th= "June"
      %th= "July"
      %th= "August"
      %th= "September"
      %th= "October"
      %th= "November"
      %th= "December"
  %tbody
    - @students.each do |obj|
      %tr
        %td= obj.first_name
        %td= obj.last_name
        - @months.each do |month|
          %td 
            - if month.detect { |date| date[:student_id] == obj.id }
              - payment = month.detect { |date| date[:student_id] == obj.id }
              = payment[:date]
            - else
              no
```

The strange thing is, that it is not working until I search anything, I can`t sort through columns, the pagination is not handled, but when I search anything, the datatables come to life :D, the table is beeing paginate and I can sort through columns.

Any idea why ?

Comment: Can you include your whole `coffeescript` ?

Comment: I have updated the question, but there is nothing more in my payments.coffee then I have already posted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the assets, I changed them and now it works fine :)

application.js.coffee:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require turbolinks
#= require bootstrap-sprockets
#= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
#= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
#= require_tree .
```

application.scss:

```
 *= require_self
 *= require font-awesome
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
 *= require_tree .
```